# Windows to linux fileshare is sometimes using old (cached) version of file

Tags: linux, windows-7, file-sharing, cache, fstab

I have a fileshare on Windows 7 that I'm accessing from a linux (ubuntu lucid) virtual machine running in VirtualBox.

When I change a file in windows, then don't access it for a while (an hour or two or more) in the linux filesystem, it either uses the old/unchanged version of the file, or it uses a truncated or corrupted version of the file.

I'm using fstab and cifs, and haven't had any other problems.

Running *mount -a* doesn't update the caching - I'm not really sure whether it's caching at the windows side or linux.

The two actions that update to the newer version of a file are:
- restarting the linux virtual machine
- resaving the file with a different filesize

Is there a way to turn off or improve the caching?

I had a look through the Win7->folder->Sharing settings, and couldn't see anything useful there.

Comment: It's quite likely to be cached by the `cifs` filesystem on Ubuntu. (You can always use Wireshark to make sure.)

Comment: @Grawity - post that as an answer.

Comment: So I looked at the cifs caching more, and you can turn it off with the forcedirectio option: [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/disable-caching-on-the-cifs-nfs-client.html) After a day of use it seems like it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Windows filesharing probably isn't doing this. What format is the file? The application on one side or the other may be mangling the file when it's changed by one.

Comment: They're just text files - php, html, sql, etc